# django-rest-framework filter by date=None

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am using `django-rest-framework` with `django-filter`. I need to retrieve a list of Widgets where the `date` property is `None`, but no matter what query I have tried, I am getting either empty responses or full, unfiltered responses.

Here's how I have defined the viewset and filterset.

```
class WidgetFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    date = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(name='date', lookup_type='exact')
    no_date = django_filters.DateTimefilter(name='date', lookup_type='isnull')
    class Meta:
        model = Widget
        fields = ['date',]

class WidgetSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Widget
    filter_class = WidgetFilter
```

The following queries result in empty `[]` responses:

```
?date=None
?date=0
?date=NULL
?date=False
?date=2012-05-24T11:20:06Z  # a known and correct date
```

The following queries result in all objects being returned:

```
?date=
?no_date=True
?no_date=False
?no_date=1
?no_date=0
```

Any help is very much appreciated! I have been unable to find any information on using dates (or passing `None` as a filter value) with `django-filter` specifically via `django-rest-framework`.

---

In case there is no more elegant way, here is how I bodged my workaround, but I'd still like to know of a solution that uses `django-filter`, if one exists.

```
class WidgetSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Widget

    def get_queryset(self):
        if 'no_date' in self.request.QUERY_PARAMS:
            return self.model.objects.filter(date=None)
        return self.model.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Specifying `isnull` directly in the filter's `name` argument as `'date__isnull'` seems to be working for me with Django REST Framework 3.1.3.

```
class WidgetFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    date = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(name='date')
    no_date = django_filters.BooleanFilter(name='date__isnull')
    class Meta:
        model = Widget
        fields = []
```

Comment: I have had trouble getting *__isnull to work with the above style of code.

Comment: The problem seems to be with django_filters.BooleanFilter not being able to understand True/False properly. Using from django_filters.rest_framework import filters, filter and then filterset.FilterSet and filters.BooleanFilter works as it seems to be passing a BooleanWidget to it as an argument.

Answer (score 9):

Running `django-filter==1.0.4` and `djangorestframework==3.6.3`.

The correct answer didn't work because module paths have changed in `django-filter` (BooleanFilter moved to django_filters.rest_framework).

And the `__isnull` didn't work either, I had to use lookup_expr:

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters


class WidgetFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    no_date = filters.BooleanFilter(name='date', lookup_expr='isnull')

    class Meta:

        model = Widget
        fields = ( 'date')
```

Got the answer from https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/743

Now I can filter by "no date" using http://localhost:8000/widgets/?no_date=True

Answer (score 8):

I ran into a similar situation today, and it appears as if out of the box django rest framework* supports this filter as:

```
~/your_endpoint/?date__isnull=True
```

This matches up with how the the equivalent ORM query would look. If that's ugly, you can use the docs example to transform that query parameter to something else without having to override `get_queryset`

- I'm using 2.4.3, but I don't believe this is a new thing

Comment: Could you give us your DRF settings ? and viewset class ?
It doesn't work for me :/

Comment: @GuillaumeEsquevin, check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull

Answer (score 5):

In case there is no more elegant way, here is how I bodged my workaround, but I'd still like to know of a solution that uses `django-filter`, if one exists.

```
class WidgetSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Widget

    def get_queryset(self):
        if 'no_date' in self.request.QUERY_PARAMS:
            return self.model.objects.filter(date=None)
        return self.model.objects.all()
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why this wouldn't be an acceptable and/or elegant solution for the stated problem? Works fine.

Comment: @PaulMaurer This does not add docs for filter automatically. Writing code for those docs may be harder than using FilterSet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter_fields`.

```
class WidgetSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Widget
    filterset_fields = {
        'date': ['exact', 'isnull']
    }
```

url query : `?date__isnull=True` or `?date=1989-03-09`

Answer (score 1):

I've done this for choice filters, which is (arguably) more useful:

```python
class NullableChoiceFilter(django_filters.ChoiceFilter):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        choices = dict(kwargs['choices'])
        null_text = choices.pop(None, 'null')
        kwargs['choices'] = ((None, '------'), ('null', null_text)) + tuple(choices.items())
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value == 'null':
            return super().filter(qs, Lookup(lookup_type='isnull', value=True))
        else:
            return super().filter(qs, value)
```

and then

```python
class MyFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = ...

    @classmethod
    def filter_for_lookup(cls, f, lookup_type):
        if lookup_type == 'exact' and f.choices:
            return NullableChoiceFilter, {'choices': f.choices}
        return filters.FilterSet.filter_for_lookup(f, lookup_type)
```

I know this doesn't answer exactly your question, but this is the first google result for "django rest framework filter null."

Answer (score 0):

Update: `name` must now be `field_name`... and `filter_class` is now `filterset_class`.

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters


class WidgetFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    no_date = filters.BooleanFilter(name='date', lookup_expr='isnull')

    class Meta:
        model = Widget
        fields = ('date')

class WidgetSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Widget
    filterset_class = WidgetFilter
```